# How to store key-value

Tags: javascript

I have array of elements

```
mapa = new Map();
someArray = ["5 5", "5 6", "5 12", "4 12"];

grupByRow() {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.someArray.length; i++) {
   const key = this.someArray[i].split(' ')[0];
   const value = this.someArray[i].split(' ')[1];
   this.mapa.set(key, value);
  }
}
```

When i try this the value is overwritten for the same key, Is some way to store key and array value key =>  5, value => [5,6,12];

Comment: Question is unclear!

Comment: You create a variable called `key` but then you pass `row` to the `.set()` function.

Answer (score 2):

You have to store an array in each Map entry:

```
for(const entry of someArray) {
   const [row, value] = entry.split(" ");
   if(mapa.has(row)) {
     mapa.get(row).push(value);
   } else {
     mapa.set(row, [value]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**@Wojciech**, you can also try to use the JavaScript's objects to accomplish this task as follows.

Sample output

```
{
    "4": [
        "12"
    ],
    "5": [
        "5",
        "6",
        "12"
    ]
}
```

Code

```js
var someArray = ["5 5", "5 6", "5 12", "4 12"];

var obj = {}

for(var i=0; i<someArray.length; i++) {
 numbers = someArray[i].split(/\s+/)  // regular expression technique for multiple spaces
 
 if(obj[numbers[0]] === undefined)
  obj[numbers[0]] = [numbers[1]]
 else
  obj[numbers[0]].push(numbers[1])
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4))

/*
{
    "4": [
        "12"
    ],
    "5": [
        "5",
        "6",
        "12"
    ]
}
*/

// console.log(obj['4'])
// // [ '12' ]

// console.log(obj['5'])
// // [ '5', '6', '12' ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish it with `reduce`.

```
var someArray = ["5 5", "5 6", "5 12", "4 12"];

var result = someArray.reduce((all, item) => {

    const [key, val] = item.split(' ');

    if (!all.has(key)) all.set(key, []);

    all.get(key).push(val);

    return all;

}, new Map());

console.log(result.get('5'));
```

You can also do the same with a regular object instead of `Map`:

```
var someArray = ["5 5", "5 6", "5 12", "4 12"];

var result = someArray.reduce((all, item) => {

    const [key, val] = item.split(' ');

    if (!all.hasOwnProperty(key)) all[key] = [];

    all[key].push(val);

    return all;

}, {});

console.log(result['5'])
```

Comment: If key don't exist is created empty array,  should created key -> pair

Comment: @WojciechAbacki What are you referring to as `pair`?